# ¿Cómo puedo ejecutar un bloque de codigo de PHP cada cierto tiempo?

Tags: javascript, php

Estoy creando un sitio web donde el objetivo es tener solo una sesión por usuario, logre hacer esto con algunas validaciones y agregando campos a mi BD, entonces supongamos que si el usuario ingresa con su usuario y contraseña en Chrome puede navegar sin problema, si el mismo usuario en otro navegador ya sea Firefox ingresa con su usuario y contraseña, en la sesión de Chrome al recargar la pagina o pasar a otra pagina directamente se cierra la sesión , pero lo que quiero hacer es que se cierre sesión al instante al momento que se inicie la otra sesión o si no es posible entonces que se haga en un determinado tiempo esto para no esperar a que recargue la pagina o cambie a otra.

este es mi codigo PHP donde tengo la validación, investigue que puedo hacerlo con ajax, pero no entiendo como hacerlo, alguien me podría orientar en esto por favor. Se los agradezco por adelantado.

```
$userById = $connection_s->getUsers($_SESSION["id_user"]);
    if ($userById["fecha_acceso"] <> $_SESSION["fecha_acceso"]) {
         echo"<script>location.href='logout.php';</script>";    
    }
```

No se que mas podría poner de codigo, este esta es mi validación.

Comment: Investiga sobre los cron jobs

Comment: En este caso solo veo posible que cada X tiempo ejecutes una petición AJAX para determinar si se ha iniciado sesión en otro navegador y actuar en consecuencia. Haciendo un long polling. Otra opción podría ser mediante ws. @pwron los cron se ejecutan de lado servidor por lo que para este caso no valdrían

Comment: Hola Luis, por seguridad es recomendable almacenar todos las sesiones para asi poder tener un registro en caso de violacion de seguridad al usuario, entonces lo ideal es que al momento de crear la sesion le asignes un tiempo de vida en la base de datos, y asi mediante validaciones terminar la sesion, en dado caso que trate de iniciar sesion en otro navegador o incognito tendrias que actualizar el final de la sesion anterior. Es decir, crea una columna por ejemplo `session_end` y ahi almacenas la fecha hasta la cual sera la valida esa sesion.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario @Ruben lo tendré en cuenta lo que me comentas